# Viewing objects in javascript ( under the hood )

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, console, q

Im very curious as to how objects are displayed in nodejs and in this case promises. When using `console.log(promiseObject)` the output is of type

`{state:pending}`

This seems very weird to me since a function `.then()` is invoked on that object so i would expect to see that there.

Try for yourself with this code

```
 function a(){

    var deferred = q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve();
    },4000)

    return deferred.promise;
}

var p1 = a()
console.log(p1) 
//outputs {state:pending} while i was expecting something like
//while i was expecting it to be {state:pending,then:function()}
```

Feels very arcane to me. I've also had similar problems in printing objects in the browser, seems like some fields are.. hidden? ( though i know of no such thing in javascript )

Comment: Didn't you find `then` in prototype ?

Comment: the fields aren't hidden, but the console can format stuff however it wants. since JSON doesn't show methods, you're often at the mercy of the console styling choices when trying to decipher composite objects. note that normally, you shouldn't even be able to get the state of the promise, so you know there's more than meets the eye somewhere between the object and your eyeballs...

Comment: Try this : `console.log(JSON.stringify(promiseObject));`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: that's not going to show much... OP can log stuff like `Object.keys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, often on the `p1.constructor.prototype` instead of `p1` itself.

Comment: I marvel at the fact that JSON.stringify() in this scenario yields an empty object instead of the string as in :'{state:pending}'

Extra confusion reeking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a debugger, your browser has probably a good one. F12 in your browser and click the *Run* button below and you can explore a Promise object (works in Chrome/Chromium, Edge, Firefox):

```js
console.clear();
var a = new Promise(function(res, rej) { res(); });
console.dir(a);
```

`then()`, `catch()` and other functions are in the `__proto__` property.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works, im just curious how i can replicate this in NodeJS.

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis You can use a tool supporting NodeJS debug, like Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
var p1 = a()
console.log(p1)
```

here `p1` is calling a function which returns a promise. so when you console log that promise you will see the status of promise.
But you want the object do something like

```
function a(){

var deferred = q.defer();

setTimeout(function(){
    var data = {status: 'resolved', value: '3'};
    deferred.resolve(data);
},4000)

return deferred.promise;
}

a().then(function (data) {
  console.log(data); //prints {status: 'resolved', value: '3'}
}
```

hope it helped

Comment: Yes but where is the then() function located. Im assuming its within the promise but i cannot see it and im trying to figure out a way of seeing it. Also this doesnt answer the fact that if you do this

var p1 = a()
console.log(JSON.stringify(p1))

you get an empty object. All these seem a little fishy to me, i expected an object is an object and thats it.

Comment: no then() is not within the promise. then() function is applicable on promise not cantained in it.