# Why does a returned Promise not have a method on it .then when logged to the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, bluebird

I understand that a new promise has a .then method on it.

But when I console log the promise returned from getUserData('jeresig') I get this object logged to the console (with no .then method).

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

Is .then actually on the new promise object or perhaps it only gets added to the object later asynchronously?

So does that mean .then is called asynchronously even though it looks synchronous?

```
let Promise = require('bluebird'),
    GitHubApi = require('github'),

let github = new GitHubApi({
  version: '3.0.0'
});

function getUserData (user){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      github.user.getFollowingFromUser({
        user: user,
        per_page: 2
      }, function(err, res){
        if (err){ reject(err) }
        else {
          resolve(res)
        }
      })
    })
}

console.log(getUserData('jeresig'))

  // .then(function(data){
  //   console.log('data', data)
  // })
  // .catch(function(error){
  //   console.log('error', error)
  // })
```

Comment: Try `console.log(getUserData('jeresig').__proto__)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing promise objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35912540/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

The `.then()` handler is already there.  This is just an issue with what you're looking at in the console.

It's on the prototype of the object which is not shown by default in `console.log()`.  Since it looks like you are looking at a Bluebird promise, if you look at the returned promise in the console in Chrome, you can expand the object in the console and see everything that is on the promise object, including the methods on the prototype.  `.then()` is there from the moment the promise is created.

You can also see for sure that it's there by doing this:

```
var p = getUserData('jeresig');
console.log(p.then);
```

And, `.then()` has to be there initially or the whole concept of the promise will not work because you call `.then()` on it synchronously.  That's how you register your interest in knowing when the promise is resolved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.then` is actually on the new promise object after creation (it in Promise prototype). And it is synchronous, because it still add callbacks to fulfill and reject events.

Try

```
console.log(getUserData('jeresig').then)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So does that mean .then is called asynchronously even though it looks
>   synchronous?

`then` method is synonymous with "do something after this promise is resolved". `then` behaves differently according to the Promise State (Polymorphism) which can confuse initially unless you read the source or spent some time understanding the concept.

If `Promise1` is resolved already, then it `returns` a `Promise2` to you and also settles that `Promise2` with the transformation function supplied by `then`. If `Promise1` is not resolved at that point, it registers a function that would get called after `Promise1` is resolved and `returns` `Promise2`. In either case you immediately get a `Promise2 object`. `callbacks` doesn't return anything to you which is not really `functional` programming, it just relies on after effect.

The main idea of `Promise` vs the normal `callback` is that it returns an `Object` to you immediately which is called the `Promise Object`. The advantage is that you can immdeiately attach a future event to it by using the `then` when this `Promise` say `Promise1` is completed and not somewhere else in the program. This is highly scalable say if you want to loop and attach something `then.then.then` etc!

This `return Object` is an important concept of `Promise`, if you didn't get this `Object` in return you would have to do this in the `callback1` function somewhere else in the program and not instantly. Imagine having to register one more aysnchronous call after `callback1`. It starts to get really messy. Everything works, however it will start getting complex to maintain. And you are not going to write functional programming like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786369/452102 which is really an idiomatic way to write things.

Going through an implementation of `Promise` will be more beneficial to learn the concepts since there are lot of places where API behaves differently depending on the situation. The benefit of this `Promise` abstraction is that, once the end user gets used to it, it all looks very seamless.